# Existence of truth values

Tags: logic

I don't understand how there can be a "mathematical statement for which no proof or disproof can be given, but for which a truth value exists".

In mathematics, is it assumed that every constructable statement not containing free variables has a truth value?

Comment: If we assumed that every constructable statement had a truth value, we would have to banish the concept of a variable.  We can construct, or write, a statement like "(A + B) = C" where A, B, and C range over the natural numbers and we do not implicit assume any quantification.  But, there is no way to determine whether this statement is true, nor false.  If we assume some quantification like "for all A, for all B, for all C, (A + B) = C" then it's false.  But, if we assume some quantification like "there exists an A, there exists a B, there exists a C; (A + B) = C", then it's true.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I modified  the question.

Comment: "for which no proof or disproof can be given" in the context of a specific theory (set of axioms).